# How to sort the values of each obs of a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have this data.set

```
  people <- c("Arthur", "Jean", "Paul", "Fred", "Gary")
  question1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 2, 5)
  question2 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 3)
  question3<- c(1, 0, 2, 2, 4)
  question4 <- c(1, 5, 2, 1, 5)

  test <- data.frame(people, question1, question2, question3, question4)

  test
```

Here is my output :

```
     people question1 question2 question3 question4
   1 Arthur         1         1         1         1
   2   Jean         3         0         0         5
   3   Paul         2         1         2         2
   4   Fred         2         0         2         1
   5   Gary         5         3         4         5
```

I want to order the results of each people like this (descending order based on values from left to right columns)  in a new data.frame. Ne names of the new columns are letters or anything else.

```
     people          A        B         C         D
   1 Arthur         1         1         1         1
   2   Jean         5         3         0         0
   3   Paul         2         2         2         1
   4   Fred         2         2         2         0
   5   Gary         5         5         4         3
```

Comment: @sindri_baldur That's not a dupe, that question is on sorting by *columns* not by rows.

Comment: @RuiBarradas my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `tidyverse` (i.e. `dplyr` and `tidyr`):

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-people, names_to="variable",values_to = "values") %>% 
  arrange(people, -values) %>% 
  select(people, values) %>% 
  mutate(new_names = rep(letters[1:4], length(unique(test$people)))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = new_names,
              values_from = values)
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  people     a     b     c     d
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Arthur     1     1     1     1
2 Fred       2     2     1     0
3 Gary       5     5     4     3
4 Jean       5     3     0     0
5 Paul       2     2     2     1
```

## Explanation:

1. bring data into 'long' form so we can order it on the values of **all** the 'question' variables.
2. order (`arrange`) on `people` and `-values` (see above)
3. remove the not used variable `variable`
4. create a new column to hold the new names, name them A-D, for each value of `person`
5. bring the data into 'wide' form, creating new columns from the new names

Answer (score 2):

With base R `apply` function `sort` to the rows in question but be carefull, `apply` returns the transpose:

```
test[-1] <- t(apply(test[-1], 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE))

test
#  people question1 question2 question3 question4
#1 Arthur         1         1         1         1
#2   Jean         5         3         0         0
#3   Paul         2         2         2         1
#4   Fred         2         2         1         0
#5   Gary         5         5         4         3
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
test %>%
 pivot_longer(-people) %>%
 group_by(people) %>%
 arrange(desc(value), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
 mutate(name = LETTERS[1:n()]) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")

  people     A     B     C     D
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Arthur     1     1     1     1
2 Fred       2     2     1     0
3 Gary       5     5     4     3
4 Jean       5     3     0     0
5 Paul       2     2     2     1
```